# Dataframe filtering with multiple conditions

Tags: python, dataframe, filtering

I have a data frame (transfers) that I need to filter based on its comparison with another data frame (make_costs).

transfers:
[image]

make_costs:

[image]

Here is what I need:
Remove SourceEquipmentID and DestinationEquipmentID combinations when TransferType is 'Make' or 'MakeTransport' and a combination of SourceEquipmentID x DestinationEquipmentID is not found in make_costs.

Here is my code:

```
mask = ((~transfers['TransferType'].isin(['Make', 'MakeTransport'])) |  (transfers[['SourceEquipmentID', 'DestinationEquipmentID']] <=  make_costs[['SourceEquipmentID', 'DestinationEquipmentID']].values))

transfers1 = transfers[mask]
```

I am getting the following error:

```
236 mask = ((~transfers['TransferType'].isin(['Make', 'MakeTransport'])) |
--> 237         (transfers[['SourceEquipmentID', 'DestinationEquipmentID']] <=  make_costs[[
238             'SourceEquipmentID', 'DestinationEquipmentID']].values))

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/common.py:81, in _unpack_zerodim_and_defer.<locals>.new_method(self, other)
 77             return NotImplemented
 79 other = item_from_zerodim(other)
---> 81 return method(self, other)
```

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/arraylike.py:52, in OpsMixin.**le**(self, other)
50 @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("**le**")
51 def **le**(self, other):
---> 52     return self._cmp_method(other, operator.le)
File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:7442, in  DataFrame._cmp_method(self, other, op)
7439 def _cmp_method(self, other, op):
7440     axis: Literal[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8mCN.png) = 1  # only relevant for Series other case
-> 7442     self, other = ops.align_method_FRAME(self, other, axis, flex=False, level=None)
7444     # See GH#4537 for discussion of scalar op behavior
7445     new_data = self._dispatch_frame_op(other, op, axis=axis)

```
File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py:288, in align_method_FRAME(left, right, axis, flex, level)
285         right = to_series(right[0, :])
287     else:
--> 288         raise ValueError(
289             "Unable to coerce to DataFrame, shape "
290             f"must be {left.shape}: given {right.shape}"
291         )
293 elif right.ndim > 2:
294     raise ValueError(
295         "Unable to coerce to Series/DataFrame, "
296         f"dimension must be <= 2: {right.shape}"
297     )

ValueError: Unable to coerce to DataFrame, shape must be (81, 2): given (6, 2)
```

Both data frames have different shapes by design. I am trying to eliminate from "transfers" all combinations SourceEquipID x DestEquipID that do not exist in "make_costs" data frame

Please, help!!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in the following way (using concatenation and isin():

```
transfers['key'] = transfers['SourceEquipmentID'] + transfers['DestinationEquipmentID']
mlist = set(make_costs['SourceEquipmentID'] + make_costs['DestinationEquipmentID'])

transfers = transfers[((transfers.TransferType.isin(['Make', 'MakeTransport'])) &
        (transfers['key'].isin(mlist))) | transfers.TransferType.isin(['Buy', 'Transport'])]  

transfers.drop('key', axis=1, inplace=True)
```